# How do I populate a join table using Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2

So I following database setup, i have created a form when creating a blog post with a dropdown for tags however on submit I want it to populate the join table.

The below only works if I manually set the tag ID.

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save(false);
        $tags->blog_id = $model->id; 
        //$tags->tag_id = 1; 
        $tags->save(false); 
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'tags' => $brands,
        ]);
    }
```

Form Field Setup

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($tags, 'tag_id',
  ArrayHelper::map(tags::find()->all(), 'id', 'title')) ?>
```

**Table/Database Structure below:**

Blog
-id (PK)
-title
-content

Blog_category
-id (PK)
-blog_id (FK)
-tag_id (FK)

Tags
-id
-title

**UPDATE:**

Not sure if the below is the best way however it works, any improvements welcomed.

```
        foreach ($_POST['Tags']['tag_id'] as $tag){
            $tags = new Tags();
            $tags->blog_id = $model->id;
            $tags->tag_id = $tag; 
            $tags->save(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using tags in assignment

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $modelTags = load(Yii::$app->request->post('tags')));
    $model->save(false);
    $tags->blog_id = $model->id; 
    $tags->tag_id = $modelTags->tag_id; 
    $tags->save(false); 
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'tags' => $brands,
    ]);
}
```

*PS the use of ->save(false) should be limited to the test phase in case of validation problems. If you don't remove this flag you could be inconsistent set of data in db.*

Comment: thank you that worked but i dont understand why it didnt without assignment since default forms using a single model dont require to.

Comment: seem load, load all model (include tags) . I can't affirm for sure because i don't see all the code.. it would be better to explicitly load $tags. But the default form use both the vars you send in render $tags inclueded in fact when submit both are posted ..

Comment: I thought it worked but it actually hasnt the record in the db was when i did it manually setting the value within the controller rather than post value.

Comment: the following works  $_POST['Tags']['tag_id']; but its not ideal is it?